# emacs/elisp: What is the hash (pound, number sign, octothorp) symbol used for?

Tags: emacs, elisp

What does this do?

```
(add-hook 'compilation-mode-hook #'my-setup-compile-mode)
```

...and is it different than

```
(add-hook 'compilation-mode-hook 'my-setup-compile-mode)
```

Answer (score 122, accepted):

There is no difference:

```
(eq 'my-add #'my-add)
```

yields `t`

The `#` can be used in front of a `lambda` expression indicating to the byte-compiler that the following expression can be byte compiled, see the docs for [Anonymous Functions](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Anonymous-Functions.html).  But there's nothing to compile in the case of a symbol.

In general, it is used in the [printed representation](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Printed-Representation.html#Printed-Representation) along with the left angle bracket (<) to indicate that the object printed is a description (but cannot be read).  For example:

```
#<buffer foo.txt>
```

It is also used in constructs by the reader to represent circular structures.  See the docs for [Read Syntax for Circular Objects](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Circular-Objects.html).

And then you have its use for denoting the [base for integers](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Integer-Basics.html#Integer-Basics), e.g. `#x2c -> 44`.

Plus more I'm sure.

Comment: According to [this article](http://endlessparentheses.com/get-in-the-habit-of-using-sharp-quote.html), one good reason for applying `#` to a lone symbol is to get diagnostics at compile time if that symbol is undefined.

Comment: It's not quite true that "there's nothing to compile in the case of a symbol." The byte compiler interprets #'car to mean "I am always referring to the function `foo', not the symbol foo." It may then actually inline the definition of foo in the byte-compiled output.  (Edit: nope, that's actually wrong. #'symbol will not be byte-compiled any differently than 'symbol -- it's just a marker of intent.)

Comment: Perhaps still mention that `'symbol` represents `(quote symbol)` and `#'symbol` represents `(function symbol)` syntactically.

Answer (score 34):

The should-be-comprehensive list can be found at the top of the [Emacs lisp reference index](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Index.html).

**Edit**: Or even more conveniently, from within Emacs itself:

- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `info` <kbd>RET</kbd> (open the info browser)
- <kbd>d</kbd> <kbd>m</kbd> `elisp` <kbd>RET</kbd> (open the elisp manual)
- <kbd>I</kbd> `#` <kbd>RET</kbd> (list the entries for `#` in the index)

Answer (score 32):

I found this question while searching for what the hash meant in something I found while hacking `mode-line-format`:

```
#("-%-" 0 3
  (help-echo "Display as tooltip when mouse hovers or with display-local-help."))
```

which is a format used for [text properties in strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Text-Props-and-Strings.html) where:

- **`"-%-"`**, text to be propertized: one dash and a [%-construct](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/_0025_002dConstructs.html#g_t_0025_002dConstructs) that results in "dashes sufficient to fill the remainder of the mode line", resulting in the famous Emacs `------`.
- **`0`**, the first character upon which the text properties apply.
- **`3`**, the last character upon which the text properties apply, *i.e.* the entire `"-%-"`.
- **`(help-echo "...")`**, a property and a string as its argument.

This can be created with the [`propertize` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Changing-Properties.html):

```
(propertize "Hover over me!" 'help-echo '"congratulations!")
```

[image: (insert (propertize "Hover over me!" 'help-echo '"Congratulations!"))]

would be the same as `#("Hover over me!" 0 14 (help-echo "Congratulations!"))`:

[image: Small example.]

If you're using font lock mode, using the `buffer-substring` command might produce something like this:

```
(buffer-substring 1 28) ; First 27 characters in the current buffer
 ⇒ #(";; This buffer is for notes"
     0 3
     (fontified t face font-lock-comment-delimiter-face)
     3 27
     (fontified t face font-lock-comment-face))
```

So you could create something like:

[image: Showing the corresponding propertize function for multiple properties.]

Comment: Link for `propertize` seems broken. See this instead: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Text-Props-and-Strings.html

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference if you want to pass a closure around:

```
(setq lexical-binding t)

(defun foo () (message "outer"))
(let ((x 5))
  (cl-flet ((foo () (message "inner: %d" (+ x x))))
    (setq y 'foo)
    (setq z #'foo)))
(funcall y)
(funcall z)
```

Outputs

```
outer
inner: 10
```

Though I think that's only because the `cl-flet` macro has special handling for `#'` aka `(function ...)`. When you macroexpand it you get:

```
(let*
    ((--cl-foo--
      (cl-function
       (lambda nil
         (message "inner: %d"
                  (+ x x))))))
  (progn
    (message "%S" #''foo)
    (setq y 'foo)
    (setq z --cl-foo--)))
```