# The #' in common lisp

Tags: common-lisp, quote

In chapter 3 of Practical Common Lisp book there's an example of a SQL-like select and where functions. Here's a simplified version of it:

```
(defun where (x) 
   #'(lambda (item)
     (> item x)))
```

and it is used like this:

```
(remove-if-not (where 2) (list 1 2 3 4))
```

Earlier in the book it is explained that the `#'` sequence is used to state that it is followed by a function name, rather than a variable that requires evaluation. I don't understand why it's needed here. I tried implementing the `where` function without it and it worked as well:

```
(defun where (x) 
   (lambda (item)
     (> item x)))
```

I tried googling for it, and, as you can imagine, with such a sequence of characters it wasn't a very fruitful search. And I don't know the name of this thing.
Is there any particular reason why it's needed in the above code?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/2701698/309483

Comment: found with [this google query](https://www.google.de/search?q=common%20lisp%20hash%20symbol)

Comment: nowadays, you can find this question with "lisp #'" on Google

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is the precise [page in Hyperspec](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_dhb.htm) which deals with the standard macro character "sharp" followed by "single quote".

To make it simple, this reader macro expands to enclose the following form into `(function <form>)` s-expression. This effectively tells the parser that the form is callable.

`lambda` is a macro, which generates the code, which already contains the `(function <form>)`, but historically and for consistency, the alternative form, which is obtained from the reader macro with sharp + quote, is often used too.

Here's [Writing lambda expressions in common lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13213611/writing-lambda-expressions-in-common-lisp) (another StackOverflow question) which covers in-depth the particular case of `(lambda <form>)`

Comment: Specifically, #'(lambda () nil) is NOT a macro invocation, but a function literal and (lambda () nil) invokes a macro-expander that expands to #'(lambda () nil).

Answer (score 7):

Note: `*print-pretty*` is `NIL` for these examples.

```
(defun where (x) 
  #'(lambda (item)
      (> item x)))
```

In above function `where` you are creating an anonymous function and you are returning it as a closure (the function plus variable binding for `X`). Since you are returning it as a value, you have to write `(FUNCTION (LAMBDA ...))`. `#'(lambda ...)` is a notation which is shorter, but results in the same - using the reader macro `#'`:

```
CL-USER 74 > (read-from-string "#'(lambda (foo) (1+ foo))")
(FUNCTION (LAMBDA (FOO) (1+ FOO)))
```

You can also write:

```
(defun where (x) 
  (lambda (item)
    (> item x)))
```

During the definition of Common Lisp it has been added to be able to write above code. It is also identical to the `(function (lambda ...))` form. In Common Lisp `LAMBDA` is macro, which expands into it:

```
CL-USER 75 > '(lambda (foo) (1+ foo))
(LAMBDA (FOO) (1+ FOO))

CL-USER 76 > (macroexpand '(lambda (foo) (1+ foo)))
(FUNCTION (LAMBDA (FOO) (1+ FOO)))
T
```

So, `LAMBDA` is a macro and when the evaluator sees it as in `(lambda ...)`, it expands the form into a `(function (lambda ...))` form, which then gets evaluated.

`FUNCTION` is a special form and when the evaluator sees it, it returns a function object - in the case of `(function (lambda (foo) (1+ foo)))` it returns the anonymous function as an object:

```
CL-USER 77 > (function (lambda (foo) (1+ foo)))
#<anonymous interpreted function 406000761C>
```

So you see that `(function (lambda ...))` is the real s-expression notation to get a function object and both `#'(lambda ...)` (via a reader macro) or `(lambda ...)` (via a macro) are shorter notations in Lisp source code. It is unusual for a programmer to use the long form. Most (99.999%) use one of the shorter notations in source code.

Btw.: If the evaluator sees `function` enclosing a name of a function like this `(function sin)`, then it looks up the function binding and returns the corresponding function object:

```
CL-USER 78 > (function sin)
#<Function SIN 4110083C6C>
```

Comment: When I tried to run your code in REPL I got slightly different results. `#` doesn't seem to be replaced with `function`. In particular `(read-from-string "#'(lambda (foo) (1+ foo))")` results in `#'(LAMBDA (FOO) (1+ FOO))` and `(macroexpand '(lambda (foo) (1+ foo)))` results in `#'(LAMBDA (FOO) (1+ FOO))`. I'm using Lisp in a Box and Clozure Common Lisp.

Comment: @Max: When `*print-pretty*` is `T`, then it tries to print it that way. Set `*print-pretty*` to `NIL` and try again...

Comment: I just checked and *print-pretty* is nil

Comment: In CCL use also `(setf *PRINT-ABBREVIATE-QUOTE* nil)`.