# Why does funcall ignore the lexical scope?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm piqued by the code in [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21413009/1339987) explaining why sharp quote is needed, but what I don't understand is why `funcall` seems to skip the usual scope rules.

```
(defun test () 'red)

(flet ((test () 'green))
  (list (funcall 'test)
        (funcall #'test))) => (red green)
```

Should I understand Common Lisp as having both "local" lexically scoped symbol bindings as set by let-family functions and globally scoped variables symbol bindings as set by de- family functions?

Comment: This isn't really about `funcall`, but about `#'` or the `function` special operator.

Comment: It seems rather about `quote` to me.

Answer (score 5):

Common Lisp is assumed.

**DEFUN and friends**

DEFUN creates a *global* function binding, which can retrieved via symbols.

```
(defun foo () 'foo)
```

Above we have a function FOO.

Let's call it:

```
(funcall (function foo))   ; no lexical bound function available, so it uses
                           ; the symbol's binding
```

or

```
(funcall (symbol-function 'foo))
```

or

```
(funcall 'foo)
```

or

```
(foo)
```

All above access the same function.

Note: above shows that `(foo)` and `(funcall 'foo)` calls the same function. There is an exception: a file compiler may assume that a function `FOO` does not change. This allows a Lisp compiler to inline code or to compile to faster function calling code. Calling the function via the symbol as in `(funcall 'foo)` always results in a call to the current and latest binding - thus a lookup via the symbol is always needed.

**FLET and LABELS**

FLET and LABELS create lexically scoped function bindings. `FUNCTION` can reference such a binding. Note that these bindings can't be accessed via symbols at runtime. There are only two ways:

- calling the function `(foo)`.
- referencing the function via `(function foo)`.

Since both are using static lexical references, there is no lookup at runtime via symbols or similar. That means, symbols are not involved at runtime with lexical functions - they are only visible in the source code.

```
(flet ((foo () 'bar))   ; <- local lexical scope, function binding

   (foo)                          ; calls the lexical bound function foo
```

or

```
  (funcall (function foo))        ; calls the lexical bound function foo
```

but

```
  (funcall (symbol-function 'foo))   ; calls the symbol's binding,
                                     ; not the lexical binding
```

and

```
  (funcall 'foo)                     ; calls the symbol's binding
                                     ; not the lexical binding

)
```

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't actually have much to do with `funcall`, but rather the difference between `quote` and `function`. Try it again without the `funcall`:

```
(defun test () 'red)

(flet ((test () 'green))
  (list 'test #'test)) => (TEST #<FUNCTION (FLET TEST) {C14D26D}>)
```

One of them is a symbol, and the other is a function object - the 
(lexically bound) function value of `test`. As you can see, `quote` returns its argument (without evaluating it) - that's where the lexical scope is ignored.

Once you understand this difference, it should be fairly clear why `funcall` behaves as it does in this example (at least, if you understand how funcall operates on symbols - see the [hyperspec entry](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/fun_funcall.html)).

Answer (score 1):

The `funcall` function takes a function designator (a function object or a symbol). With `#'foo` you retrieve the function object bound to `foo`, in the lexical context this is evaluated. With `'foo`, you create the symbol foo.

When `funcall` then maps the function designator to a function, it's either simply the identity (if you pass a function object, this is used) or has to be looked up in the global environment.