# Difference between #'callee and 'callee in Common Lisp

Tags: function, lisp, common-lisp

Here is my Common Lisp code:

```
(defun caller (f)
  (format t "caller: f: ~a~%" f)
  (funcall f 10))

(defun callee (x)
  (format t "callee: x: ~a~%" x))

(caller #'callee)
(caller 'callee)
```

Here is the output I get with `clisp`:

```
$ clisp foo.lisp 
caller: f: #<FUNCTION CALLEE (X) (DECLARE (IN-DEFUN CALLEE)) (BLOCK CALLEE (FORMAT T callee: x: ~a~% X))>
callee: x: 10
caller: f: CALLEE
callee: x: 10
```

I want to know what is the difference between the syntax `#'callee` and the syntax `'callee`.

Although with both syntaxes, I am able to pass the `callee` to the `caller`, the `caller: f:` output seems to indicate that there is some subtle difference in both the syntaxes: `#'callee` seems to refer to a function object but `'callee` seems to refer to just the function name.

Here are my questions:

1. What's the difference between the `#'callee` syntax and the `'callee` syntax?
2. How is it that `funcall` is able to invoke the `callee` in both cases successfully?
3. Is there any best practice or pros and cons associated with both syntaxes due to which one is preferred over another?

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29337947/why-does-funcall-ignore-the-lexical-scope

Answer (score 1):

The difference is largely one of how the function is looked up.  If one passes a symbol to `funcall`, it is looked up in the global (rather than lexical) environment.  The relevant documentation is http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_funcal.htm.  I've slightly modified the example from the docs:

```
(defun cons* (&rest rest)
  (apply 'cons rest))

(flet ((cons* (x y) `(kons ,x ,y)))
  (let ((cons* (symbol-function '+)))
    (funcall #'cons*
         (funcall 'cons* 1 2)
         (funcall cons* 1 2))))

;; => (KONS (1 . 2) 3)
```

Comment: Since I am still a beginner with Lisp, can you please explain me which one of my examples is passing a *symbol*? Do you mean that `#'callee` is passing a function object and `'callee` is passing a symbol?

Comment: Precisely!  `#'callee` expands to `(function callee)` while `'callee` is a lisp symbol.  The online book: http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/ is a great introduction to common lisp

Answer (score 1):

`#'callee` expands to `(function callee)` while `'callee` expands to `(quote callee)`.

`#'` looks up in the function name space. (Common Lisp is a 2-Lisp, meaning it has 2 separate namespaces which allows that a function can have the same name like a variable/data - Scheme/Racket is a 1-Lisp where function and variables share the same namespace - meaning sth with a specific name is either a function or a name for some other object).

`'` doesn't look up anywhere but evaluates the following symbol name to itself a name.

`funcall` looks up its arguments name in the function name space and returns the function assigned to it. If you do a normal function call `(callee 10)`, the Lisp interpreter implicitely looks up `callee` from the function namespace, because the first position in a list which gets executed is reserved for the function name. When functionnames are given as arguments, in other positions than the first, you have to apply `funcall` or `#'` on them first, so that the interpreter knows that this name it has to lookup in the function name space and not in the normal variable name space.

Try this:

```
(defun d (x) x) ;; declares a function d in the function name space
(setf d 1)      ;; declares variable d in the variable name space
(list d #'d d #'d)
;; returns:
(1 #<FUNCTION D (X) (DECLARE (SYSTEM::IN-DEFUN D)) (BLOCK D X)> 1
#<FUNCTION D (X) (DECLARE (SYSTEM::IN-DEFUN D)) (BLOCK D X)>)
;; when `#'` is given, the d is looked up from the function name space,
;; without, d is looked up from the normal variable name space
(d d)
;; the first position d gets looked up from the function name space but 
;; the argument d from the variable name space
;; since the function d is the identity function and variable d has the value 1,
;; this evaluates the identity function on 1, thus to
1
(d #'d) ;; now the argument `d` is looked up from the function name space
;; thereby returning a function:
#<FUNCTION D (X) (DECLARE (SYSTEM::IN-DEFUN D)) (BLOCK D X)>
```