# Common lisp about naming packages and using them

Tags: common-lisp, package

I try to use Common Lisp packages, but I have several (probably naming conventions) problems, first is the use of "#:" it seems not necessary but is like [sharp-quote in functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410233/why-is-sharp-quote-notation-unnecessary-in-clisp) that is better to use depending on your context.

```
(defpackage   #:match-test
  (:use       #:match
              #:fiveam
              #:cl)
  (:export #:run!
           #:test-match)
  (:documentation "Test package for testing match project 1 of CS202"))
```

Then is in how to use that package

```
(in-package #:match-test)

(in-package :match-test)

(in-package match-test)
```

it works, but when I want to delete that package it only works with:

```
CL-USER> (delete-package (in-package #:match-test))
#<BOOLEAN <<error printing object>> {2010004F}>
```

it gives that error, but it makes the job done. It seems working with the package as an object, I also do not understand the [hyperspec](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_del_pk.htm), is a problem that I need to learn CLOS, that is true I'm a beginner learning Lisp, but I suppose that I can get a easy clarifying for my doubts.

I hope that I said it quite clearly.

Finally I want to say that I used emacs + sly + roswell and

```
CL-USER> (lisp-implementation-type)
"SBCL"
CL-USER> (lisp-implementation-version)
"1.4.6"
```

Comment: If you use uninterned symbols (like `#:FOO`) as a name in places where they are evaluated as forms (such as the argument to `DELETE-PACKAGE`), you have to quote them like any other symbol (eg `(delete-package '#:match-test)`).

Comment: Do not feel bad, the CLHS is not very approachable. Try http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DEFPACKAGE` and `IN-PACKAGE` are defined as macros. They take a literal name - a *string designator*: `foobar`, `|FOOBAR|`, `#:FOOBAR`, `:FOOBAR` or `"FOOBAR"`.

`DELETE-PACKAGE` is a function and expects a string designator, too. But since it is a function, the argument is evaluated. This means: if you want to pass the name, you have to quote it - if it is a symbol not in the keyword package. Strings and keyword symbols are self-evaluating and don't need to be quoted. Valid arguments to `DELETE-PACKAGE` are for example:

```
'foobar
'|FOOBAR|
'#:FOOBAR
:FOOBAR or ':FOOBAR
"FOOBAR" or '"FOOBAR"
```

Since `DELETE-PACKAGE` is a function, the argument gets evaluated -> you can also evaluate variables, function calls, ... as argument.

**The Error: Deleting the current package**

LispWorks:

```
CL-USER 43 > (delete-package (in-package #:match-test))

Error: Cannot delete the current package, #<The MATCH-TEST package, 0/16 internal, 2/16 external>.
  1 (abort) Return to top loop level 0.
```

SBCL:

```
* (delete-package (in-package #:match-test))

debugger invoked on a SIMPLE-TYPE-ERROR in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {10005605B3}>:
  *PACKAGE* can't be a deleted package:
    It has been reset to #<PACKAGE "COMMON-LISP-USER">.
```

Your code tries to delete the **current package** - you just used `IN-PACKAGE` to make it the current package - deleting the current package is usually not a good idea. You are shooting yourself in the foot. A Lisp might prevent that (like my example in LispWorks) or allow it - but then you have to live with the consequence.