# CPlusPlusMode: create matching parenthesis or curly brace

Tags: c++, emacs

Using CPlusPlusMode in Emacs v24.5.1, I want to auto-create matching parenthesis and curly brace when typing expressions.

More specifically, when typing, e.g., '{', CPlusPlusMode should create a matching parenthesis and move the cursor in between, like in the example below:

```
if (a < b) { 
   // cursor here: default behavior

if (a < b) {
  // cursor here: anticipated behavior
}
```

Comment: Install the `autopair` mode.

Comment: Expansive discussion on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023770/automatically-closing-braces-in-emacs

Answer (score 1):

[ElectricPair](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ElectricPair) should do what you are looking for:

> Electric Pair mode, a global minor mode, provides a way to easily
>   insert matching delimiters. Whenever you insert an opening delimiter,
>   the matching closing delimiter is automatically inserted as well,
>   leaving point between the two.

Use the snippet below in your Emacs config file to activate it by default for C++:

```
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook #'electric-pair-mode)
```

Comment: What does the # means?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701698/emacs-elisp-what-is-the-hash-pound-number-sign-octothorp-symbol-used-for